# Parsing a document in a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

How do I parse a document in a table and send it across as a JSON file to another db.

Detailed Desc:
I have crawled and taken data into a table from websites using anemone. I need to now parse it and transfer it as a JSON file to another server. I think, I will have to first convert the document in the table into nokogiri document which can be parsed and converted to json file. Any idea how can I convert the doc into nokogiri document or if anyone has any other idea to parse it and send it as a json file ?

Comment: Why would you want to represent HTML pages as JSON?

Comment: because I am storing it in a repository which is a different rails application. It is not a html page. I will be passing the parsed document as a JSON and not the whole HTML document.

Comment: So are you looking for something more than  http://www.google.com/search?q=nokogiri+tutorial ? If so, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @Jeremy Weathers...i was looking for something more than nokogiri... a way to parse it and send it across as a hash in json... i am sorry if i was not able to xplain u the real issue. but things are sorted now able to send it as a json in a hah to another rails app after using nokogiri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the answer long time back,  I basically made use of REST to send message form one application to another, i sent it across as a hash. And the obvious one, I used nokogiri for parsing the table.

```
def post_me
     @page_hash = page_to_hash

    res = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://127.0.0.1:3007/element_data/save.json'),@page_hash)
  end
```

For sending the hash from one application to another using net/http.

```
def page_to_hash
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'nokogiri'
    require 'open-uri'
    require 'domainatrix'

    #page = self.page.sub(/^<!DOCTYPE html(.*)$/, '<!DOCTYPE html>')
    hash={}
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(self.page)
    doc.search('*').each do |n|
      puts n.name
    end
```

Using Nokogiri for parsing the page table in my model. page table had the whole body of a webpage.

```
file_type = []

    file_type_data=doc.xpath('//a/@href[contains(. , ".pdf") or contains(. , ".doc")
                          or contains(. , ".xls") or contains(. , ".cvs") or contains(. , ".txt")]')
    file_type_data.each do |href|
      if href[1] == "/"
        href = "http://" + website_url + href
      end
      file_type << href
    end
file_type_str = file_type.join(",")
    hash ={:head => head,:title => title, :body => self.body,
      :image => images_str, :file_type => file_type_str, :paragraph => para_str, :description => descr_str,:keyword => key_str,
      :page_url=> self.url, :website_id=>self.parent_request_id, :website_url => website_url,
      :depth => self.depth, :int_links => @int_links_arr, :ext_links => @ext_links_arr
    }
```

A simple parsing example and how i formed my hash.

Answer (score 1):

Nokogiri is your best bet for the HTML parsing, but as for converting it to JSON you're on your own from what I can tell.

Once you have it parsed via Nokogiri it shouldn't be terribly hard to extract the elements you need and generate JSON that represents them. What you're doing isn't a very common task, so you'll have to bridge the gap between Nokogiri and whichever gem you're using to generate the JSON.

Comment: thanks eric. How can I use nokogiri on documents in a table. I have a result table where in I am storing the HTML page. Now I need to parse it. Any help on how can I do that.

Comment: @noobie: I take it you mean an HTML table? You should take a look at xpath, a simple (and somewhat universal) syntax for selecting elements from a DOM tree. You can use the xpath function included with Nokogiri to grab specific elements. An example that would be related to tables would be grabbing all the rows. The xpath syntax for that would be: '//table[@id="foo"]/tr'. Hope that helps!